# Disabling the internal keyboard on a MacBook Pro for drawing tablet use?'

Tags: mac, keyboard, macbook, macbook-pro

This has been asked before, here: [How to disable the internal keyboard on a MacBook Pro?](https://superuser.com/questions/185819/how-to-disable-the-internal-keyboard-on-a-macbook-pro)

I'd like to disable the internal keyboard on my MacBook Pro so I can put a drawing tablet on top.

The previous answers' problems:

- The pages for Lockey, KeyboardCleanTool and Macifier is dead
- Keyboard Cleaner and CatNip lock out the screen
- The terminal command and is a super clunky solution when I won't be
  working with an external keyboard.
- Mouse keys might work but is also kind of clunky.

Any other ideas? Definitely appreciated!

Comment: Do you actually need to disable the keyboard? The MacBook Pro has recessed keys, so you may be able to just lay the tablet across it, supported by the non-recessed metal above and below the keyboard. Though where you rest your hands may affect the usability of this approach.

Comment: I won't know for sure until I buy I guess, but I have an external keyboard that I've used before, and setting that on top of the internal keyboard doesn't work well.

Comment: I just tried it myself with a 15", unibody, non-retina MBP, and a Wacom Intuos Pen & Touch Medium (that's the previous generation). The results were not good. The keyboard actually didn't seem to have any problems. No repeating characters, a visual inspection between the tablet and notebook suggested it wasn't pressing down on anything, and the keyboard viewer wasn't showing anything pressed. But the tablet itself didn't work, neither with the stylus, nor my finger. I tried using a broad ~.75" book as a spacer and it still didn't work. Holding it up, it seemed to finally start working ~2" up.

Comment: So the keyboard doesn't seem to be the problem, but the tablet itself is. It might be specific to Wacom's technology, so if you're planning on another brand, you *might* not have any trouble at all. Then again, you might. I'd recommend you either start looking for a thick ~2-3" spacer, (probably non-metallic, and keep an eye on your MBP's temperatures), or plan to use your tablet in a different location.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably just plan to prop up my Mac instead.